# How to carry some data between page using model in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to carry some data by updating the ( adding ) some properties to existing model. But it's not carried to next page. so i tried like this:

```
combineArray:Ember.computed(function(){

        let trans = Ember.A();
        let index = 0;
        var that = this;

        this.get('model.ccList').map(function(card,num){

            let name = card.get('cardName');
            let numb = card.get('cardNum');

            card.get('cardtransactions').map(function(transaction){

                console.log( 'transaction', JSON.stringify(transaction) )

                let temp = {};
                temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(  transaction ));
                temp.cardName = name;
                temp.cardNum = numb;
                temp.selected = false;
                temp.handlingFee = that.setHandlingFee( transaction.get('localCurrencyAmount') );
                trans.push( Ember.Object.create().setProperties(temp) );

            })

        });

        this.model.set('processedTrans', trans  );

        console.log( this.model.get('processedTrans').get('firstObject'));

        return this.model.get('processedTrans');

    }),
```

Using the above approach I am finding that, some of data's are missing. so what is the correct way to carry some data between page?

Using service not sets for me. because I have no.of pages. I am looking to update a model with required datas.

Comment: You should **never** set anything in a computed property because they are cached and this causes hard-to-predict and hard-to-debug side-effects. If you want a value to be set when another values is set, just do that explicitly yourself

Comment: Can't I use model for transport some data between pages?

Comment: Rather than solving your problem the way you have shown, can you please just state what you're trying to accomplish?  As you say "carrying data between pages" is almost meaningless in Ember, since it is a single-page application.

Comment: @steve I have a parent page, I is getting model from store. same model used to all child pages. so each child page having some data to send to it's sibling(s). so I am trying to update the same model. it can shared to all pages.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you begin thinking in terms of `route` rather than page.  Ember `Route`s are a hierarchy, so you would have parent routes and child routes.

As an example, consider the following in your router configuration:

```
this.route('post', {
    path: '/post/:post_id'
  }, function() {
  this.route('edit');
});
```

In this case, there is a parent (`post`) and a child (`post.edit`).

In your Route for `post`, you would have:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
```

For the Route for `post.edit`, you would have:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.modelFor('post');
  }
});
```

So here, the child and the parent are using the same model.  If you need additional stuff in your child route, you can do that in the model hook (again, this is the child route):

```
export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    let post= this.modelFor('post');
    return post.get('someOtherProperty');
  }
});
```

In this case, the child's model will be the value of the parent's model's `someOtherProperty` attribute.

Hope this helps you think about your problem in a different way.

Comment: I agree, instead of get, can't I set some value?

Comment: You want to modify the model because a user visited a particular route?  I would rethink the flow of your design.  Rather than thinking "I need to setup the model so the following page can use it", think instead "When the following page sets up its model, it can use the parent model".

Comment: I am looking sharing. Between children